# Get Secret from Azure Keyvault using nodejs

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-active-directory, azure-keyvault

I need to read the list of users in the Azure active directory. The client has created a Graph API application but they do not want to share the client secret of the application, instead they asked us to use the Key vault. How to access from the node.js application the key to retrieve the list of users?

I tried the below one but gave error and  I am not sure how to authenticate.

```
const { DefaultAzureCredential } = require("@azure/identity");
const { SecretClient } = require("@azure/keyvault-secrets");

const credential = new DefaultAzureCredential();

const vaultName = "lsm-keyvault";
const url = `https://${vaultName}.vault.azure.net`;

const client = new SecretClient(url, credential);

const secretName = "Demo";

async function main() {
  const result = await client.setSecret(secretName, "MySecretValue", {
    enabled: false
  });

  console.log(result)
}
```

Comment: Where did you run your code? In local or azure web app?

Comment: @JoyWang ; In Local

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, if you run the code in local, the `DefaultAzureCredential` will use the environmental variables automatically.

So in your case, you need to [register an application with Azure AD](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-create-service-principal-portal#register-an-application-with-azure-ad-and-create-a-service-principal), and get the [`tenant id`, `client id(i.e. application id)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-create-service-principal-portal#get-tenant-and-app-id-values-for-signing-in), [`client secret(i.e. application secret)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-create-service-principal-portal#create-a-new-application-secret), set the [environmental variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/secrets/quick-create-node#set-environmental-variables),  `AZURE_CLIENT_ID`, `AZURE_CLIENT_SECRET`, and `AZURE_TENANT_ID`.

For the 403 error you got, I notice you said `It added as a compound entity`, based on my experience, you did not add the correct service principal related to the AD App correctly to the `Access policies` of the keyvault. If you add it correctly, it will appear as `APPLICATION`, not `COMPOUND IDENTITY`.

So when you add it, you could search for the `client Id(i.e. application Id)` or `the name of your App Registration` directly, make sure you add the correct one. I gave the details in this [similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62017017/9455659), you could refer to it.

To [retrieve the secret](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/secrets/quick-create-node#retrieve-a-secret), the `Get` permission is enough, the code should be

```
const retrievedSecret = await client.getSecret(secretName);
```

I notice you use `client.setSecret` in your code, it is used to [save a secret](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/secrets/quick-create-node#save-a-secret), to use it, you may need the `Set` permission.

For more details, see [Quickstart: Azure Key Vault client library for Node.js (v4)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/secrets/quick-create-node).

**Update:**

> I have to eventually need to deploy this but not in azure but in another environment. How do I set the environment variables and access it.

If so, you need to change your code to authenticate, use the three values directly in the code.

Change the lines

```
const { DefaultAzureCredential } = require("@azure/identity");
const credential = new DefaultAzureCredential();
```

To

```
const { ClientSecretCredential } = require("@azure/identity");
const credential = new ClientSecretCredential(tenantId, clientId, clientSecret);
```

See - https://www.npmjs.com/package/@azure/identity/v/1.0.3#authenticating-as-a-service-principal

Comment: Thank you . you are right . I created a new app with right permission. and it worked. I have one final question , Now i need to set the environmental variables locally for it to work. I have to eventually need to deploy this but not in azure but in another environment. How do I set the environment variables and access it.

Comment: The `DefaultAzureCredential` will fallback to the `ManagedIdentityCredential` which should work in the environments where you would deploy your code like a VM or App Service. See [How to set and get secrets from Azure Key Vault with Azure Managed Identities and Node.js](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/azure-samples/azure-sdk-for-js-keyvault-secrets-get-nodejs-managedid/get-set-keyvault-secrets-managed-id-nodejs/)

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is follow the below steps:

- Create an App in the Azure Active Directory (Service Principal) from App Registrations.
- Go to Key Vault resource, Access Policy blade, assign read access to this Azure AD App (Service Principal) that we created in the above step.
- Set these 3 Environment variables `AZURE_CLIENT_ID`, `AZURE_TENANT_ID`, and `AZURE_CLIENT_SECRET` in your App Service. Get the values of these variables from the app that we created in step 1.
- Use `DefaultAzureCredential` that we are already using now. This will automatically pick the credentials from the environment variables that we defined in App Service for the authentication.

Another way is to obtain Key Vault token dynamically and use that token to get the secrets from the Key Vault - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/azure-samples/app-service-msi-keyvault-node/app-service-msi-keyvault-node/

**Helpful Reference:**

- https://www.rahulpnath.com/blog/defaultazurecredential_from_azure_sdk/

Comment: Thanks Ankush. I get the below error . I have added the access policy with all the permission . It added as a compound entity but still i get the below error
{
"name": "RestError",
"code": "Forbidden",
"statusCode": 403,
"request": {
"streamResponseBody": false,
"url": "https://lws-keyvault.azure.net/secrets/Demo/?api-version=7.0",
"method": "GET",
"headers": {
"_headersMap": {
"content-type": {
"name": "content-type",
"value": "application/json; charset=utf-8"
},

Comment: Are you done with all the steps? At which moment, you get this error?

Comment: I have done all the steps. While running the app i get this error