# Get token from azure with azure funtions JavaScript

Tags: javascript, azure, azure-functions

I am trying to get an access token from login.microsoftonline.com with azure functions in javascript, any idea how to do it?

Beforehand thank you very much.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here are few work arounds that you can try

**WAY - 1**
You can retrieve the [access token from postman](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/servicebus/get-azure-active-directory-token#use-postman-to-get-the-azure-ad-token) and then store the same to Azure Key vault and [get the secrets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63343346/get-secret-from-azure-keyvault-using-nodejs) in your azure functions.

**WAY - 2**
Using MSAL for Node.js. The ADAL for node.js package makes node.js apps to connect to AAD and gain access to AAD-protected web pages.

I'm just highlighting the most significant parts here, but the link below will take you to GitHub where you can get the whole website code as well as some information on the library it utilises.

```
var clientId = 'yourClientIdHere';
var clientSecret = 'yourAADIssuedClientSecretHere'
var authorityHostUrl = 'https://login.windows.net';
var tenant = 'myTenant';
var authorityUrl = authorityHostUrl + '/' + tenant;
var redirectUri = 'http://localhost:3000/getAToken';
var resource = '00000002-0000-0000-c000-000000000000';
var templateAuthzUrl = 'https://login.windows.net/' + 
                        tenant + 
                        '/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=' +
                        clientId + 
                        '&redirect_uri=' + 
                        redirectUri + 
                        '&state=<state>&resource=' + 
                        resource;

authenticationContext.acquireTokenWithAuthorizationCode(
    req.query.code,
    redirectUri,
    resource,
    clientId, 
    clientSecret,
    function(err, response) {
      var errorMessage = '';
      if (err) {
        errorMessage = 'error: ' + err.message + '\n';
      }
      errorMessage += 'response: ' + JSON.stringify(response);
      res.send(errorMessage);
    }
  );
```

You can refer [AAD Library for Node js](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-nodejs) for more information on this.